# MVC6 Default Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Maybe I just been awake too many hours and totally overseeing something but I am using MVC6 ASP.NET 5.0 to develop an AngularJS website. Inside my wwwroot I have a index.html page and it was working just fine but then applied an update and now all of a sudden I just get a blank white screen: Developer Tools tells me:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Inside my startup I have the following:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseDefaultFiles(new Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles.DefaultFilesOptions() { DefaultFileNames = new[] { "index.html" } });
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Some reason I am still getting a blank white page and nothing loading when I am debugging.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must also specify `app.UseStaticFiles()`. [From the docs:](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/static-files.html)

> In order for your Web app to serve a default page without the user having to fully qualify the URI, call the `UseDefaultFiles` extension method from `Startup.Configure` as follows. Note that you must still call `UseStaticFiles` as well. This is because `UseDefaultFiles` is a *URL re-writer* that doesn’t actually serve the file. You must still specify middleware (`UseStaticFiles`, in this case) to serve the file.

Comment: Oh my I cannot believe I forgot that. Yes you are totally correct.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the answer above:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
  ...
  // Serve the default file, if present.
  app.UseDefaultFiles();
  app.UseStaticFiles();
  ...
}
```

http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/static-files.html